# Async http-request, node.js modules and variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm currently struggling to get variable values from one node.js module into another. This is my current problem:

I am fetching data from a REST API via https-request:

```js
// customrequest.js

sendRequest( url, function( data, err ) {
if(err) {
  console.log('--- Error ---');
  console.log( err );
}
else {
  console.log('--- Response ---');
  console.log(data);
  // output: data
  return data;
}
module.exports = { sendRequest }
```

And my index.js file:

```js
// index.js
let sendRequest = require('./customrequest');
let req;
req = sendRequest('google.com');
console.log(req);
// output: undefined
// how can I get the variable set, when request is getting data in response?
```

I totally understand, that the request to an API takes some time for the response. One solution is, that I just put everything into one js file. But as my project will get bigger over time, the modular approach is my goto-solution. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: I encountered, that it's not a problem of the modules.export, but of the delayed return from the request. How can this be solved?

Comment: Where is the http-request method?
By the way, you have to use callbacks in order to log the incoming results from the REST API request.

Comment: sendRequest( url, function( data, err ) … I just named it for the purpose of readability different here. It's basicly done with node-fetch (fetch() …).

Answer (score 0):

Node uses callbacks for this situation. Try something like this:

```js
// customrequest.js

sendRequest(url, callback)
module.exports = { sendRequest }
```

```js
// index.js
let sendRequest = require('./customrequest');
let req = sendRequest('google.com', function (data, err) {
   if (err) { 
     //handle error here
   }
   console.log(data);
};
// output: undefined
// how can I get the variable set, when request is getting data in response?
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The problem I encounter is somewhat different. I solved it with this code snippets … using async and await.

```js
// request.js

const fetch = require('node-fetch')

async function myRequest (somestring) {
  try {
      let res = await fetch('https://api.domain.com/?endpoint='+somestring)
      if (res.ok) {
        if (res.ok) return res.json()
        return new Error (res.status)
      }
  } catch (err) {
      console.error('An error occurred', err)
  }
}

module.exports = { myRequest }




// index.js

const request = require('./requests')
const myRequest = request.myRequest

let myVar;

myRequest('somestring')
  .then(res => myVar = res.result)


setInterval(() => {
    myRequest('somestring')
      .then(res => myVar = res.result)
    console.log(myVar)
  }, 1000)
```

The async function and awaits return a promise. This promise is, when resolved, assigned to a variable.